# Problem converting simple urdf file in collada

Tags: urdf, moveit, collada-urdf, collada, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a problem converting a very simple urdf file in collada (.dae) to use ikfast. I have a more complicated robot but I started to have this error even with a very simple urdf file:

```
I/O error : No such file or directory
I/O error : No such file or directory
error : xmlNewTextWriterFilename : cannot open uri

Document successfully written to prova.dae
```

but the prova.dae file does not exist.
The prova.urdf file that I am trying to convert is:

```
<robot name="prova">

<link name="base_link" />
<link name="link1"/>

<joint name="j1" type="revolute">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="link1"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  <limit effort="40" lower="-0.785" upper="0.785" velocity="3.1415"/>
</joint>

</robot>
```

so just pure kinematics.
I am using ros indigo with openrave compiled from source (latest_stable branch). I am using the command:

```
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada prova.urdf prova.dae
```

in the same folder of the urdf file. My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.
thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198995/problem-converting-simple-urdf-file-in-collada/) by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salsaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21523/salsaman/) on 2015-04-07**:
Same problem here. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem. Here comes my "workaround" (it is quite a bit of work ...)

Define a new robot in openRAVE XML Format:

http://openrave.programmingvision.com/wiki/index.php/Format:XML

( <source xml> in the Wiki is not part of the code!)

Install openrave (from source) and start an interactive terminal

```
openrave.py -i
```

here you can use

```
env.Reset(); env.Load('rv4fl.xml')
```

to load/reload your model. Do so until it looks fine. Press ESC to go into Manipulation Mode. Try selecting a link by pressing CTRL and clicking it. Now check if it moves as expected when you move the mouse.

Now convert to COLLADA:

```
openrave -save test.dae rv4fl.xml
```

you can check that as well

```
openrave test.dae
```

Now you need the ids of base and end effector

```
openrave-robot.py test.dae --info links
```

create the ik-fast solution:

```
python `openrave-config --python-dir`/openravepy/_openravepy_/ikfast.py --robot=test.dae --iktype=transform6d --baselink=0 --eelink=6 --savefile=test.cpp
```

install moveit_ikfast from git and create a moveit_package

```
rosrun moveit_ikfast create_ikfast_moveit_plugin.py mitsubishi_rv4fl manipulator mitsubishi_rv4fl_moveit_plugins  test.cpp
```

This will also automatically set up ik_fast in your moveit_config package

---

Originally posted by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) with karma: 229 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this has been fixed by newer version of collada library, see  https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/118#issuecomment-164554380

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-12-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1